# How to open jupyter notebook from Windows 10 task bar

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

Through some wizardry I cannot recall, I managed to install and implement Jupyter Notebook with an icon that opens Jupyter directly in browser

I am occasionally asked how I did this. However, and slightly emparisingly, I cannot remember how I did this and am unable to help. I cannot seem to recreate this Jupyter Icon in any other set up

[image: The Icon on the taskbar is in the image below]

Also, in attempting to recreate this Icon, I somehow managed to implement two Anaconda Prompts, Anaconda PowerShell Prompt and Anaconda Prompt

What is the difference between the two? Which one should I remove?

Answer (score 2):

> I somehow managed to implement two Anaconda Prompts, Anaconda PowerShell Prompt and Anaconda Prompt

That is standard. The first `Anaconda Prompt`, will open the legacy `cmd` configured for `conda`. The second will open a powershell configured for `conda`. SO just keep both and use the one you are more comfortable with.

> How to open jupyter notebook from Windows 10 task bar

Simply search for `jupyter` in the start menu and select `Pin To Taskbar`
[image]

**Creating it manually**

In case the above does not work, then you can manually create a shortcut and pin it to the taskbar. For that, we will need two paths, which for me are these:

```
pathBase=C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3  #main folder of miniconda (or anaconda)
pathEnv=C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\envs\py37 #Folder of the environment where jupyter notebook is installed
```

Then you do the following steps:

`Right Click` on Desktop->`New`->`Shortcut`, enter as target path:

```
<pathBase>\python.exe <pathBase>\cwp.py <pathEnv> <pathEnv>\python.exe <pathEnv>\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/
```

replacing the paths with the ones from above. Save the shortcut and then do `Right Click`->`Properties`.

Now you can change the `Start In` directory to wherever you want the notebook to start. Additionally, you can change the icon to the jupyter icon, which is in

```
<pathEnv>\Menu
```

Now you have

1. A shortcut to start the notebook on your desktop
2. The possibility to simply do `Right Click`-> `Pin to Taskbar` for that Shortcut

Comment: If I search for Jupyter, nothing appears

Comment: @Hamster If that is not present, then you can manually create a shortcut on your desktop and then pin it to taskbar. I will update my answer

Comment: @Hamster added the description how to add the shortcut manually

Answer (score 1):

Search for Anaconda Navigator in your computer then Right Click and Select "Open file location".
[image: windows search for anaconda]

In the folder that is opened you can find shortcuts of programs that are installed via anaconda. You can copy and paste them anywhere you want.

[image: shortcuts folder]